# How to retrieve a class name?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, metaprogramming

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to retrieve the class name, also if it is namespaced. For example, if I have a class named `User::Profile::Manager` I would retrieve the `Manager` string from that using some unknown to me Ruby or Ruby on Rails method and in a *secure* way.

*BTW*: What other "usefull" information that are "commonly" used can I get for the class?

Comment: You want a string `"Manager"` from a string `"User::Profile::Manager"` or from a reference to the class `User::Profile::Manager`

Comment: @Dogbert - From the reference to the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some useful simple metaprogramming calls:

```
user = User::Profile::Manager.new(some_params)
user.class # => User::Profile::Manager
user.class.class # => Class
user.class.name # => "User::Profile::Manager"
user.class.name.class # => String

# respond_to? lets you know if you can call a method on an object or if the method you specify is undefined
user.respond_to?(:class) # => true
user.respond_to?(:authenticate!) # => Might be true depending on your authentication solution
user.respond_to?(:herpderp) # => false (unless you're the best programmer ever)

# class.ancestors is an array of the class names of the inheritance chain for an object
# In rails 3.1 it yields this for strings:
"string".class.ancestors.each{|anc| puts anc}

String
JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::String
Comparable
Object
PP::ObjectMixin
JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object
ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable
Kernel
BasicObject
```

If you want the lowest-level class from `User::Profile::Manager` I'd probably do the following [using a regex for this seems like overkill to me ;)]:

```
user = User::Profile::Manager.new
class_as_string = user.class.name.split('::').last # => "Manager"
class_as_class = class_name.constantize # => Manager
```

**Edit:**

If you actually want to look through some more metaprogramming calls, check the docs for the  [Object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html) and [Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html) classes, and check out the google results for "Ruby Metaprogramming".

Comment: +1, split is definitely better than the regex gsub I had posted :)

Comment: It is better to use 'User::Profile::Manager.to_s.demodulize' # => Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `class` method:

```
class A
  class B
  end
end

myobject = A::B.new

myobject.class

=> A::B
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @JCorcuera's answer, some other useful information can be found with kind_of? and methods

```
class A
  class B
        def foo
        end
  end
end

myobject = A::B.new

p myobject.class
=> A::B

p myobject.kind_of? A::B
=> true

p myobject.methods
=> [:foo, :nil?, :===, :=~, ...

p myobject.methods.include? :foo
=> true
```