# Module.nesting within instance_eval/exec or module_eval/exec

Tags: ruby, class, module, nested

I came up with this question when I was trying to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336921/how-to-retrieve-a-class-name). The following is an expected behaviour:

```
module A
  p Module.nesting
end
# => [A]
```

But the following:

```
A.instance_eval{p Module.nesting}
A.instance_exec{p Module.nesting}
A.module_eval{p Module.nesting}
A.module_exec{p Module.nesting}
```

all return `[]`. Why do these not work as the above?

**Additional Question**

Mu is too short suggested an interesting point. If that is correct, then `Module.nesting` would be one of the methods and variables that are dependent on the literal context like `Method#source_location`, `__FILE__`. Is this understanding correct? If so, can someone provide the inventory of these methods/variables that are dependent on the literal context? I think it would be useful for reference.

Comment: ["Returns the list of Modules nested at the point of call"](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000441) but there is no open `module` when you say `A.module_eval` you're just acting in the context of `A`. `Module.nesting` seems to be more about talking to the parser than the Ruby run-time environment.

Comment: @mu is too short Inspired by your comment, I added to my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Warning**: This is a little long and rambling. A bit of a tour through the Ruby source code seems necessary as the documentation is a bit thin. Feel free to skip to the end if you don't care about how sausage is made.

---

The 1.9.2 `Module.nesting` is implemented in `eval.c` like this:

```
static VALUE
rb_mod_nesting(void)
{
    VALUE ary = rb_ary_new();
    const NODE *cref = rb_vm_cref();

    while (cref && cref->nd_next) {
        VALUE klass = cref->nd_clss;
        if (!(cref->flags & NODE_FL_CREF_PUSHED_BY_EVAL) &&
            !NIL_P(klass)) {
            rb_ary_push(ary, klass);
        }
        cref = cref->nd_next;
    }
    return ary;
}
```

I don't know the Ruby internals that well but I read the `while` loop like this: extract from the `cref` linked list all the nodes that are associated with a class-like thing but didn't come from `eval`. The `NODE_FL_CREF_PUSHED_BY_EVAL` bit is only set in here:

```
/* block eval under the class/module context */
static VALUE
yield_under(VALUE under, VALUE self, VALUE values)
```

A bit more grepping and reading reveals that `instance_eval` does end up going through `yield_under`. I'll leave checking `instance_exec`, `module_eval`, and `module_exec` as exercises for the reader. In any case, it looks like `instance_eval` is explicitly excluded from the `Module.nesting` list; this is, however, more of a distraction than anything else, it just means that you won't see something the evals mentioned.

So now the question is "what are `NODE` and `rb_vm_cref()` all about?".

If you look in `node.h` you'll see a bunch of NODE constants for the various Ruby keywords and language structures:

- `NODE_BLOCK`
- `NODE_BREAK`
- `NODE_CLASS`
- `NODE_MODULE`
- `NODE_DSYM`
- ...

so I'd guess that `NODE` is a node in the instruction tree. This lines up nicely with my

> `Module.nesting` seems to be more about talking to the parser

conjecture in the comment. But we'll keep going anyway.

The `rb_vm_cref` function is just a wrapper for `vm_get_cref` which is a wrapper for `vm_get_cref0`. What is `vm_get_cref0` all about? It is all about this:

```
static NODE *
vm_get_cref0(const rb_iseq_t *iseq, const VALUE *lfp, const VALUE *dfp)
{
    while (1) {
        if (lfp == dfp) {
            return iseq->cref_stack;
        }
        else if (dfp[-1] != Qnil) {
            return (NODE *)dfp[-1];
        }
        dfp = GET_PREV_DFP(dfp);
    }
}
```

All three arguments to the function come straight out of this control frame:

```
rb_control_frame_t *cfp = rb_vm_get_ruby_level_next_cfp(th, th->cfp);
```

The `iseq` appears to be an instruction sequence and the `lfp` and `dfp` are frame pointers:

```
VALUE *lfp;                 // cfp[6], local frame pointer
VALUE *dfp;                 // cfp[7], dynamic frame pointer
```

The definition of `cref_stack` is relevant:

```
/* klass/module nest information stack (cref) */
NODE *cref_stack;
```

So it looks like you're getting some sort of call or nesting stack out of `rb_vm_cref`.

---

Now back to the specifics at hand. When you do this:

```
module A
  p Module.nesting
end
```

You'll have `module A` in the `cref` linked list (which is filtered to produce the `Module.nesting` result array) as you haven't hit the `end` yet. When you say these:

```
A.instance_eval { puts Module.nesting }
A.instance_exec { puts Module.nesting }
A.module_eval   { puts Module.nesting }
A.module_exec   { puts Module.nesting }
```

You won't have `module A` in `cref` anymore because you've already hit the `end` popped `module A` off the stack. However, if you do this:

```
module A
  instance_eval { puts Module.nesting.inspect }
  instance_exec { puts Module.nesting.inspect }
  module_eval   { puts Module.nesting.inspect }
  module_exec   { puts Module.nesting.inspect }
end
```

You'll see this output:

```
[A]
[A]
[A]
[A]
```

because the `module A` hasn't been closed (and popped off `cref`) yet.

To finish off, the [`Module.nesting` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000441) says this:

> Returns the list of Modules nested at the point of call.

I think this statement combined with the review of the internals indicates that `Module.nesting` does in fact depend on the specific literal context in which it is called.

If anyone with more experience in the Ruby internals has anything to add I can hand this over to the SO community as a community wiki.

---

**UPDATE**: All of this applies to `class_eval` as well as it does to `module_eval` and it also applies to 1.9.3 as well as it does to 1.9.2.

Comment: Thanks for the impressive and detailed explanation. Wiki might be a good idea.